# Integration of exponential function $\int_{\frac12}^{\frac34} e^{-e^{1/x}}dx$

Tags: integration

How to compute the  value of this integral $$\int_{\frac12}^{\frac34} e^{-e^{1/x}}dx$$? I have tried integration by parts method . No idea how to do that. Please help me.

Comment: What makes you think it's possible?

Comment: Why do you think it is possible for a human to compute this integral? It may well be, but at first glance it seems like it is one of those impossible integrals. The integrand is unusually nasty

Comment: I mean, we can give you unpleasant series solutions if you wish. I doubt they'd reduce to a nice closed form

Comment: The best you can hope is to find a power series solution or a numerical aproximation

Comment: Have you tried looking for weird substitutions? For example, if you try to brute force it with a silly substitution like $u=-e^{1/x}$, you can get it into the form: $$-\int_{-e^2}^{-e^{4/3}} \dfrac{e^u}{u(\ln (-u))^2}du$$ which is obviously not a helpful substitution, but is a vastly different problem than you started with. Perhaps there is a weird substitution that can make this problem computable?

Comment: @FShrike just because finding a closed form antiderivative is not possible doesn't mean you cannot find an exact closed form value of a definite integral for example $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\ dx=\sqrt{\pi}$. That being said, I don't see much hope for this problem from the mathematics I've seen. It would be a good approximate the value of this integral problem IMHO.

Comment: Spectrum, you could use the Composite Simpson's rule and you would get that $$\int_{\frac12}^{\frac34} e^{-e^{1/x}}dx\approx0.3058870630871644$$ See this link: [Composite Simpson's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Composite_Simpson's_rule)

Comment: @N8tron I know! But one generally needs symmetries in the integrand or domain of integration, or recourse to some other trick (e.g. contour integration, of which I am a fan). None of the methods I'm familiar with look relevant here. The given domain of integration is seemingly random, and OP hasn't motivated the problem at all

Answer (score 2):

*No way to have a closed form.*

Since you are integrating over a small range, use a series solution
$$e^{-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$$
$$\int_{\frac12}^{\frac34}e^{-e^{\frac{1}{x}}}\,dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{4^{n+1} (n+1)!}$$ Now
$$a_n=e^{-e^2}\,b_n$$ and the first $b_n$ are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & b_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 4 e^2 \\
 2 & 16 e^4-32 e^2 \\
 3 & 352 e^2-384 e^4+64 e^6 \\
 4 & -4864 e^2+8704 e^4-3072 e^6+256 e^8 \\
 5 & 80384 e^2-209920 e^4+117760 e^6-20480 e^8+1024 e^{10} \\
 6 & -1540096 e^2+5502976 e^4-4362240 e^6+1187840 e^8-122880
   e^{10}+4096 e^{12} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Consider the partial sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{a_n}{4^{n+1}\, (n+1)!}$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 0 & 0.00015450 \\
 1 & 0.00072528 \\
 2 & 0.00175061 \\
 3 & 0.00250042 \\
 4 & 0.00231472 \\
 5 & 0.00192613 \\
 6 & 0.00215178 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

It is oscillating but stabilize quite quickly close to the "exact" value which is $0.00215194$.